# How to clean Maven snapshots deployed on the server?

Tags: maven

On the snapshot server, Maven keeps all the generated snapshots. I want to clean all but the latest ones that are deployed on the server.

How can I tell Maven to only keep the N latest snapshot versions and to remove the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not controlled by Maven.  Instead, it is more to do with the repository manager.

For example, in Nexus, you can setup scheduled task to remove snapshots from hosted repositories.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. In my case, the repo is a static web server, and I deploy via SSH.

Comment: I believe the easiest way you can do is write a little script, and have a cron job to do the cleanup periodically.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use a Repository Manager like Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva which have tasks for such purposes or in case of releases the according SNAPSHOT's will automatically be deleted.